# How to make thin hair look thicker?

Tags: personal-care, hair

Hair always looks fuller & thicker on the day that I shampooed. The day after that, it feels so light & thin. Because of this, could not set or comb my hair the way I want to. Light application of hair cream helps but that would not me of much help on the third day.

I shampoo once every three days.

Comment: How long is your hair? How do you wear it? Do you use a hair-dryer? Do you habitually wear a hat or a helmet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have started to use wash&go, shampoo and conditioner in one, in the shower. It saves a lot of time in the shower, its very cheap and doesn't hold my hair down! 
Once my hair is dry its got so much volume that it lasts for days. For a little bit extra smoothness I use hair oil or coconut oil on it while its still damp.

Salt spray also helps with volume.

Answer (score 0):

Dry Shampoo. [Teasing Brush](https://www.amazon.com/s/ref=nb_sb_noss_1?url=search-alias%3Daps&field-keywords=teasing%20brush). Helps my hair and different options for making your own Dry shampoo or buying.